# How to split list of dictionary in one column into two columns in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

[image]I want to split the filteredaddress column of the spark dataframe above into two new columns that are Flag and Address:

```
customer_id|pincode|filteredaddress|                                                              Flag| Address
1000045801 |121005 |[{'flag':'0', 'address':'House number 172, Parvatiya Colony Part-2 , N.I.T'}]
1000045801 |121005 |[{'flag':'1', 'address':'House number 172, Parvatiya Colony Part-2 , N.I.T'}]
1000045801 |121005 |[{'flag':'1', 'address':'House number 172, Parvatiya Colony Part-2 , N.I.T'}]
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values from `filteredaddress` map column using the keys:

```
df2 = df.selectExpr(
    'customer_id', 'pincode',
    "filteredaddress['flag'] as flag", "filteredaddress['address'] as address"
)
```

Other ways to access map values are:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.select(
    'customer_id', 'pincode',
    F.col('filteredaddress')['flag'],
    F.col('filteredaddress')['address']
)

# or, more simply

df.select(
    'customer_id', 'pincode',
    'filteredaddress.flag',
    'filteredaddress.address'
)
```

Comment: the above code is throwing error: cannot resolve 'from_json(`filteredaddress`)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, '`filteredaddress`' is of map<string,string> type.

Comment: @peeps the dataframe you showed in your question does not have a map type column. Could you do `df.show()` and copy the output to your question?

Comment: df.show() added the output to my question